# How to hide Mysqli empty row/column?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have two tables for my project.
1. Categories
2. Items

In catregories table currently i have 4 categories where 1 row is empty, I would like to hide the row that is empty OR show a message "Nothing is found".

This is the code i am working on.

```
<?php 

$query = "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY category_name ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if(!$result){
die("Database query failed");
}

?>

    <ul">
      <li><a href="index.php"></a></li>
      <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
        <li><a href="products.php?category=<?php echo urlencode($row["category_id"]); ?>"><?php echo $row["category_name"]; ?></a></li>
      <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    <?php mysqli_free_result($result); ?>
```

Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "empty" row ?

Comment: Explain better... show an example with desired output and current output

Comment: By "row" i meant, I have Accessories, Bags, Clothing, Dinnerware so if any of them is empty then display the message or hide that category.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
if ($result->num_rows != 0){
// body here
}else{
echo "Nothing found !";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this: **EDITED**

```
 <ul>
          <li><a href="index.php"></a></li>
          <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
    if(isset($row["category_name"]) && strlen($row["category_name"]) > 1 && $row["category_name"] !=""){?>
            <li><a href="products.php?category=<?php echo urlencode($row["category_id"]); ?>"><?php echo $row["category_name"]; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
          <?php  }?>
        </ul>
        <?php mysqli_free_result($result); ?>
```

please construct html part properly.

Comment: It still displays the empty category with no message

Comment: rest of the data you are able to get or not.

Comment: Yes, data is being displayed but if i change the category_name to category_id it changes the the name of the categories to 'There is no content.' though i want this to display where the items are being displayed.

Comment: ok then, when category_name is not available in row what exactly you want to do i.e. you want to hide li or to show that there is no data kind of thing.

Comment: 1 row is empty means for this which field is empty.can you show the all 4 rows of your table.because i was thinking like the category_name is empty that's why i wrote the code like that.

Comment: Actually i want it like if Accessories is empty than it could be hidden or display a message.[link](http://postimg.org/image/41mxv8ulv/)[/link]

Comment: in this image no empty row is there but you said one row is empty.

Comment: I may be bad in explaining, Suppose the Accessories column is empty i.e it has no value than we can hide this or show the message

Comment: but Accessories is a value for column category_name not column in your shared table.

Comment: So it means it cannot be hidden if it has nothing assigned to it using relational data?

Comment: why not it is our implementation problem if you implement properly you can do any thing.any ways you are trying to show links to all li's.suppose if any column with category_name is null or empty the do not create <a></a> simply use <li> <?php echo "no content available"; ?></li>.hope your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

you asing like this?

```
  <?php 
  if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
            if($row["category_name"]!=""){ ?>
            <li><a href="products.php?category=<?php echo urlencode($row["category_id"]); ?>"><?php echo $row["category_name"]; ?></a></li>
          <?php }
      }
  } else {
   echo 'Sorry No results!'
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mayby you should try a query similiar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE category_id IS NOT NULL AND category_name IS NOT NULL ORDER BY category_name ASC
```